# iphone sdl Invalid conversion between vector type '__m64'

Tags: ios, c, iphone, xcode, sdl

I'm trying to run this code on my iphone 6. Code builds well for emulator, but for physical iphone have error.

[image]

Error in file mmintrin.h:

```
static __inline__ __m64 __DEFAULT_FN_ATTRS
_mm_cvtsi32_si64(int __i)
{
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
}
```

Part of my code (copied from SDL/Xcode-iOS/Template/SDL iOS Application/):

```
done = 0;
while (!done)
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            done = 1;
        }
    }

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    growTree(tree, depth, length_div, angle_div, grow_speed, time);

    drawTree(renderer, tree, TREE_POS_X, TREE_POS_Y);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Delay(1);
}

// shutdown SDL 
SDL_Quit();
```

And working emulator:

[image]

Comment: Please show the code.

Answer (score 0):

I build SDL using SDL2-2.0.9/build-scripts/iosbuild.sh as in SDL2-2.0.9/docs/README-ios.md (It's not working for me).

It started working, when I rebuild all using Xcode only as in the instruction step by step(http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/52_hello_mobile/ios_mac/index.php)